# How to tab through results in SWI-Prolog on Mac?

Tags: macos, prolog, swi-prolog

I am new to prolog and am just trying to get the hang of it. However, I know that you are able to press tab to run through multiple answers from a given call. Such as brother(john,X). 
If john has two brothers per the stated facts, it should show the first brother in SWI-Prolog, and then once you hit tab it shows the second brother. 
I've run my program on windows and albeit simple, it works. I am capable of tabbing to the next item.

However, on my personal computer (Mac running Mavericks), I am unable to 'tab' through the remaining possible answers. Instead, tab seems to open up some type of box that allows me to do other procedures, such as abort.

I hope this is a simple question, but how in the world can I simply TAB through results in SWI-Prolog? It's really become a distraction at this point! Google has yielded no answers for me in the last hour.

Comment: You can't simply type `SPACE` or `;` ?

Comment: Yes, that's all I needed to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

space bar to parse through possible results when using SWI-Prolog on a Mac.